# Find select using jQuery inside a var from an HTML template to load options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next problem: I'm trying to use a modal jQuery form, this one, inside, changes dynamically the content of a table by using a template loaded. This template has a select which I want to load with data in the moment I put into the document.

This is the modal form:

```
<div id="divNuevoPartido" title="Nuevo Partido a introducir" style="display:none;">
    <div id="divJugadoresDelPartido">
        <h3>Introduce n&uacute;mero de jugadores</h3>
        <select id="selectJugadoresDelPartido">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <table id="tableJugadoresDelPartido"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When 'selectJugadoresDelPartido' change, the table 'tableJugadoresDelPartido' changes dynamically depending of the number, insert this template inside the table n-times selected in 'selectJugadoresDelPartido'

This is the template, just fo 1 row:

```
<td>
   <label for="jugadorName">Jugador</label>
   <select class="selectorJugadores" name="jugadorName"></select>
   <label for="isWinner">Ganador?</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="isWinner" />
   <label for="isMvp">MVP?</label>
   <input type="radio" name="isMvp" />
   <label for="puntajeJugador">Puntaje</label>
   <input type="number" name="puntajeJugador" />
   <label for="golesJugador">Goles</label>
   <input type="number" name="golesJugador" />
   <label for="asistenciasJugador">Asistencias</label>
   <input type="number" name="asistenciasJugador" />
   <label for="salvadasJugador">Salvadas</label>
   <input type="number" name="salvadasJugador" />
   <label for="tirosJugador">Disparos</label>
   <input type="number" name="tirosJugador" />
</td>
```

And finally, here is de JS code it should insert the template n-times selected above and also load data inside the select '.selectorJugadores'

```
function refrescarTablaJugadoresPartido(numJugadores){
    $("#tableJugadoresDelPartido").empty();
    for (var iMax = 0; iMax < parseInt(numJugadores); iMax++) {
        var tmpRow = $("<tr></tr>");
        tmpRow.attr("id", iMax);
        tmpRow.load("views/templates/estadisticas_jugador_partido.html");

        if($.isEmptyObject(usersList))
            cargarJugadores();

        var tmpOption = $("<option></option>");
        tmpOption.html(usersList[0].getCodigo());
        tmpRow.find("select").html(tmpOption);

        $("#tableJugadoresDelPartido").append(tmpRow);
    }   
};
```

Everything inside the mehtod it's working but at the time I try to find the select into tmpRow, I seems it doesn't find and nothing is loaded inside.

NOTES:

- usersList is a global variable: var usersList = new Array() with an objet with two variables: codigo and nombre, working fine in that way;
- I'm loading just to test with one option, I'noticed about it :)
- cargarJugadores() it's a function which load userList array (it's working perfecly)

Any ideas?

Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the document has not been loaded at the time you call the find command, beacuse load is asynchoronous.

You could put the `find` inside a callback in load, this way:

```
tmpRow.load("views/templates/estadisticas_jugador_partido.html" , function() {

    tmpRow.find("select").html(tmpOption);

    });
```

This way, the `find` command will be called once the `load` is complete.

Comment: You should take care that tmpOption be defined before the call. Anyway, as the execution will be asynchronous, is probable that the variable be defined when it executes, no matter it was defined later in the code. But you shouldn't relay in that, because a very fasct connections would trigger the error.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, now I've done this, as you've suggested me and it's working partially, because it only load data in the last select, i'm doing this right now:   
var tmpOption = $("<option></option>");
tmpRow.load("views/templates/estadisticas_jugador_partido.html", function(){
     tmpOption.html(usersList[0].getCodigo());
     tmpRow.find("select").html(tmpOption);      
});
$("#tableJugadoresDelPartido").append(tmpRow);

Why it's only loading in the last one?

Comment: Finally I found why:
$(".rowJugador").find($("select")).append(tmpOption);
Thank you sou much for your help, it wouldn't be possible without it